# Store metakey value as an array

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

How could one grab the post meta key of `_octopus_id` and store that as an array.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Call the `WP_Query` and pull all the offices with `_octopus_id`
- Use the value of `_octopus_id` and store it in an array
- End goal: Just print out a array with just the `_octopus_id` values

Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong? The `is_array($posts)` prints out true, but I just can't figure out how to store the keys value there.

Full code:

```php
    /* Set the WP offices in an array */
    $ids = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'office',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'        => '_octopus_id',
            ),
        )
    ]);

    $posts[] = $ids->posts;

    var_dump($posts);
    var_dump(is_array($posts));
```

Comment: So you want an array of `_octopus_id` that are currently used by at least one `office`?

Comment: @kero, Correct - I'd like to loop through those 10 posts and store the _octopus_id key values into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `WP_Query` returns the meta fields for you as well. So you need to loop over the posts and run [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) manually. Assuming one `office` has at max one `_octopus_id`, you could write it like this:

```
// here we will store the ids
$octopiIds = [];

$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'        => '_octopus_id',
        ],
    ]
]);
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $octopiIds[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_octopus_id', true);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Do you really need the pagination of `WP_Query`? If not, I would suggest writing your own query via `$wpdb`s [`get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/), as it can save you alot of queries. The code above will create at least 11 queries (1 for `WP_Query`, 1 for each post to get the meta), but you can do this in only one.

(untested)

```
global $wpdb;
$octopiIds = $wpdb->get_cols(
    $wpdb->query("
        SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_octopus_id'
        WHERE pm.meta_value != '' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    ")
);
```

As an additional note, if you're storing some kind of relationship between octopi and offices here, consider using a taxonomy instead of postmeta, as it will speed things up alot.

Comment: This helped so much! Thanks a bunch!